# I get the next error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES when try to install a flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I face the next issue when try to install a flutter app on my device:

failed to install C:\Users\ALBERTO\studio_projects\z8_flutter\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl959590152.tmp/base.apk using APK Signature Scheme v2: SHA-256 digest of contents did not verify]
Error launching application on SBC3300.

It's strange because I'm running the app in debug mode, so the debug.keystore file had to be created automatically. Anyway, I created my own debug.keystore file and edited my build.gradle to make sure the project is using my keys.

command:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('C:/Users/ALBERTO/.android/debug.keystore')
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        // Otras configuraciones...
    }
```

I don't know what it can be, the origin of the problem.

I try:

- Invalidate Caches/Invalidate and restart
- Generate my own debug.keystore file
- Device factory reset
- Flutter clean
- 

```
dev {
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
```

- 

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        // Otras configuraciones...
    }
```

- 

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
   }
```